# how to prevent "URIError: malformed URI sequence" from style percent

Tags: javascript

Ive this code:

> javascript:if(document.getElementById('linky'))%20{%20%20%20%20document.getElementById('linky').value=splitdo;}else%20{tarea=document.createElement('textarea');tarea.style.position='fixed';tarea.style.top='5%';tarea.style.left='5%';tarea.style.width='400px';tarea.style.height='100px';tarea.id='linky';tarea.value=splitdo;document.body.appendChild(tarea);};void(0);

I want to decode it using `decodeURIComponent` function. Now the problem is it is giving me the error `URIError: malformed URI sequence`.
I know this problem have been asked many times in this site, but mine is a bit different.
after some work Ive fount that the problem goes to the line that it has percentage with numbers (i.e. `tarea.style.top='5%';tarea.style.left='5%';`)
If you remove the percent, no error will be thrown by that function. I know it is because of the percents followed by nothing, but I dont know how to prevent this error. I want the percents to be there, I dont want to use pixels. What should I do to keep the `5%` but prevent this error?
Can it be prevented?

Comment: % have special meaning in URLs so '%' itself should be encoded..

Comment: %20 is space, maybe just replace this token.

Answer (score 2):

`decodeURIComponent` does not work. I found I should use `unescape`. https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-TextSelection-Plugin/issues/18